# Unexpected token after http JSONP Angular

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack, meanjs

I would like to create an input field which uses the Google Places API to retrieve suggestions for the user to have it easier to fill in the field.

I am using MEAN.js and I have problems to retrieve the information using the Angular controller:

```
// Get places
$scope.getPlaces = function(val) {
    return $http.jsonp('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK', {
        params: {
            input: val,
            types: '(regions)',
            language: 'en',
            key: 'AIzaSyADMplvJfIzKFslb5KfOdZbCKK2SIYVl-E'
        }
    }).then(function(response){
            var places = [];
            angular.forEach(response.predictions, function(item){
                places.push(item.description);
            });
       return places;
    });
};
```

The view tries to retrieve the auto-suggestions using the typeahead component:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" id="location" name="location" class="form-control" ng-model="asyncSelected" typeahead="place for place in getPlaces($viewValue)" typeahead-loading="loadingPlaces" placeholder="Location">
</div>
```

I checked the console and the requests return with a 200 OK, but I get an error in the console:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

What is wrong with the http jsonp request?
How can I fix it?

Thanks
Cheers
Maurizio

Comment: Can you provide us with json and the line that this error is reffering to?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105092/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-angularjs

Comment: The post does not solve my problem... I am already using the JSON_CALLBACK param. Moreover, I am using the Google Place API.

Comment: @rtucker88 thanks for the info, but it is not exactly duplicated because I already use the JSON_CALLBACK and I do not know how to solve it.

Comment: It looks like V3 of googleapis doesn't support JSONP therefore you will need to either use V2 api or use 'proxy' on your server